# LAN adapter works every second time I turn my PC on

Tags: windows-7, networking, lan, network-adapter

I have a really strange problem and I am desperate for help now, since I could not find any solution on the internet.

Specifications first: I am using a desktop computer and a router. The router gives off wireless for the laptop in the house and my PC is connected directly via a cable coming from the router. My OS is Windows 7 32 bit.

Here is the problem : every time I turn my PC off for more than a few minutes, my internet connection stops.   To fix this, I need to turn the PC off again for like five minutes, then it is all right. So in a way, my computer takes turns of having and not having internet connection. Also, another thing is, I cannot do anything to the LAN adapter settings while this is happening - I can disable it, but when I try to enable it again, it just freezes and does not enable the adapter (also when I restart, I do not need to enable it again, even if it was disabled when I turned the PC off).

I cannot change any driver settings, it just freezes again. When I wait a couple of minutes and turn the PC off again, it is all back to normal and I can change options, enable/disable etc.

I really find no logic in this problem and I want to know if it is a Windows 7 problem before reinstalling or if it is my Network Card that needs replacement.

**EDIT**: I know it is not a router problem or ISP problem, since the laptop can connect to the internet at the time I cannot. I also switched up the cables and nothing changed, so I think the problem is not there too.

Comment: are you sure there is no loose connection? is the card securely attached , or have you tried a different cable? have a look in the windows logs, see if any hints there

Comment: The networking card is integrated in the motherboard and yeah, I did try other cables. Where are the logs located?

Comment: you could try to run "perfmon /report" (from start menu search), or you can look in the logs here "Start> right click "my computer"> manage> Event Viewer> Windows Logs> 'choose a log' right click> save all events as> save the logs

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to start your computer in safe mode, then uninstall the network driver. Further restart your computer in normal mode and install ethernet drivers.

In safe mode if you fail uninstalling your network driver, start the computer in safe mode with command prompt,

you may follow the link that might help you with it

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/181.how-to-manage-device-drivers-with-command-line.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I also suspect something is wrong with your driver. So try this out.

Comment: @Stephen - The article you linked to doesn't really have any "solution" to this problem.  We really expect answers to be higher quality then a couple comments and a link to a website.

Comment: I am worried though, how do I reinstall the network driver if I have no internet connection?

Comment: you need to first get drivers for your network card then. You can easily download it from its official website.

Answer (score 1):

It could be power management settings kicking in at the wrong time.  I've seen this happen before.

Open up Device Manager and double-click your wireless network adapter's properties page.  Then go to the Power Management tab and uncheck "Allow the coputer to turn off this device to save power".  See if that helps.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is off by default :P
I will just wait for the problem to occur again and I will try to reinstall the network drivers